# Root $ c \in F$, where $c\neq0$ $ F[x]$ and div $c^{-1}$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, roots

Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...a_{n-1}+a_nx^n $ and $\bar{f}(x)=a_n+a_{n-1}x+...+a_1x^{n-1}+a_0x^n \in F[x]$. ($F$ is a field, of course.)

> If $c\ne0$ is a zero of $f(x)$, prove $c^{-1}$ is a zero of $\bar{f}(x)$.
>
> ---

Do have an something with messy coefficients and saying c is a root and factoring out $x-c$. Wondering if there is a more elegant way?

Comment: You have $0=a_0+a_1c+...a_{n-1}c^{n-1}+a_nc^n$. Now just divide this by $c^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(c)=0$ $$ 0=a_0+a_1c+...+a_{n-1}c^{n-1}+a_nc^n $$
Div by $c^n\neq0$
$$\begin{aligned}0&=\frac{0}{c^n}=a_0c^{-n}+a_1c^{1-n}+...+a_n1c^{-1}+a_n\\
   0&=a_0(c^{-1})^n+a_1(c^{-1})^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}(c^{-1})^1+a_n 
\end{aligned}$$
$\therefore \bar {f}(c^{-1})= a_n + a_{n-1}(c^{-1})^1+...+a_1(c^{-1})^{n-1}+ a_0(c^{-1})^n=0$

Comment: FIY. THERE IS NO DIVISION IN Rings, Field. knowing that it is not hard to fix this "proof"